# Can I import others git repository to my repository?

Tags: github

I find a lot of good sources in Git. Instead of bookmarking the page I like to import others repository into my repository. 
Is this allowed? 
Is this what people do usually?
Is the other user notified when I import from his repository?
Is he notified for any changes that I make on my imported repository?
When I import, I see that all the commit history and the contributor in my repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People just [Fork](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.13/user/articles/fork-a-repo) repositories.

> A fork is a copy of a repository. Forking a repository allows you to freely experiment with changes without affecting the original project.